# Building Snapwm on FreeBSD (Problem of gcc and clang)?

Tags: compiling, freebsd, make, gnu-make

According to FreeBSD, from version 10 they use Clang/LLVM instead of gcc. on the surface of it all things should perform as been before even better. but I have faced this reality more than I want to. Some codes can't be compiled this way.
For example I tried to compile [Snapwm](https://github.com/moetunes/Nextwm). First native FreeBSD `make` is actually `pmake` and that is out of the question. So `gmake` is our choice. but issuing `gmake` on the code will produce this error:

```
gcc -g -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -c -o snapwm.o snapwm.c gmake: gcc: Command not found gmake: *** [snapwm.o] Error 127
```

So the question becomes how to compile the code that suffers from these set backs.

Comment: FreeBSD is using `clang/llvm` for the *world* and *kernel*. Nothing is preventing you from using gcc and gnu-make for ports or personal projects. As-long-I-remember *gnu-make* was named `gmake` on FreeBSD platform: this is hardly new.

Comment: @Ouki Yes but how? what would be the command? it is not that simple? Is it a way to `gmake` it with clang?

Comment: This is what *ports* are: a set of configure options and if needed patch to files and/or makefile (have a look in `/usr/ports/x11-wm/ctwm/files` for instance). There is currently no *one command* way of doing it, as there is no ports for *snapwm*. You need to do it the hard way: configure/Imake whatever you can and/or modify the makefile to reflect your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes needs some patch. I've createad which you can apply and can build with `gmake`. I didn't try the compiled `snapwm` I've tested only building process.

```
diff -ur Nextwm-master.orig/Makefile Nextwm-master/Makefile
--- Nextwm-master.orig/Makefile 2014-03-12 19:46:34.000000000 +0100
+++ Nextwm-master/Makefile  2014-04-16 13:07:08.000000000 +0200
@@ -1,12 +1,12 @@
-CFLAGS+= -g -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
+CFLAGS+= -g -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/usr/local/include/
 LDADD+= -lX11 -lXinerama
-LDFLAGS= -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro
+LDFLAGS= -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-L/usr/local/lib
 EXEC=snapwm

 PREFIX?= /usr/local
 BINDIR?= $(PREFIX)/bin

-CC=gcc
+CC=clang

 all: $(EXEC)

diff -ur Nextwm-master.orig/snapwm.c Nextwm-master/snapwm.c
--- Nextwm-master.orig/snapwm.c 2014-03-12 19:46:34.000000000 +0100
+++ Nextwm-master/snapwm.c  2014-04-16 13:03:24.000000000 +0200
@@ -27,6 +27,7 @@
 //#include <X11/keysym.h>
 /* For a multimedia keyboard */
 #include <X11/XF86keysym.h>
+#include <sys/signal.h>
 #include <X11/Xproto.h>
 #include <X11/Xutil.h>
 #include <X11/Xatom.h>
```

Comment: @r004 does it work?

Comment: hello and very much thank you.  I was very late because I moved around the snapwm to make sure it worked.